# Mailto subject referencing

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have modified an internal error page that is displayed to the user once a URL is blocked by SquidGuard. Following is the part of the script that I need some assistance with:

```
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# IE displayed self-page, if them size > 1024
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
function get_error_page($er_code_id, $err_msg='') {
    global $err_code;
    global $cl;
    $str = Array();

    header("HTTP/1.1 " . $err_code[$er_code_id]);
    $str[] = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">';
    $str[] = '<html>';
    $str[] = '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title></head>';
    $str[] = '<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF; font-family:verdana, arial, sans serif;">';

    $str[] = '<div style="padding:5px; background-color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-family:verdana,arial,sans serif; color:#2F93D1; font-size:70%;"> <p>';
      if ($cl['n'])        $str[] = "Your Node Name: {$cl['n']} </p><p> ";
      if ($cl['a'])        $str[] = "Your Node IP: {$cl['a']} </p><p> ";
      if ($cl['i'])        $str[] = "Node User: {$cl['i']} </p><p> ";
      if ($cl['s'])        $str[] = "Group: {$cl['s']} </p><p> ";
      if ($cl['t'])        $str[] = "Blacklist Category: {$cl['t']} ";
    $str[] = '</p></div><div style="background-color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; padding:20px;">';
    $str[] = '<p><img style="padding-top:20px;display: block;margin: 0px auto" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/_aRy3rhrUl64/TaOzVHF01fI/AAAAAAAACVw/H__Us1P5ghc/s800/Untitled.jpg" alt="geblockt"></p></div></div>';
    $str[] = '<div style="padding:20px; margin-top:20px; background-color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; color:#000000; font-family:verdana, arial, sans serif; font-size:80%;">';
            if ($err_msg) $str[] = '<p style="font-weight:bold; font-size:150%;"> '. $err_msg.' </p>';
            if ($cl['u']) $str[] = "<p><strong>URL: {$cl['u']}</strong></p>";
    $str[] = '<p>Because of access restrictions, your request to the above address is not allowed. </p>
    <p>Please contact <a href="mailto:firewall_support@iuass.org?subject=[HELP IS NEEDED HERE]&body=Please unblock this URL, thanks">IUASS firewall support</a> if you are of the opinion that this is not correct.</p><p>';
    $str[] = '</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><img src="http://iuass.org/system/cms/themes/default/img/logo.gif" alt="geblockt" width="315" height="44" style="padding-top:20px;display: block;margin: 0px auto"></p></div></div>';
    $str[] = '<div style="width:70%; margin:20px auto; background-color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; color:#000000; font-size:60%; font-family:verdana,arial,sans serif;">Web Filtering by <a style="color:#000000;">IUASS Firewall implementing pfSense with Squid and SquidGuard</div></div>';
    $str[] = "</body>";
    $str[] = "</html>";

    return implode("\n", $str);
}
```

What I need to do is to add the blocked url to the mailto subject in

```
<a href="mailto:firewall_support@iuass.org?subject=[HELP IS NEEDED HERE]&body=Please unblock this URL, thanks">
```

As far as I understand, the url is referred to by {$cl['u']} pointer. If I add it above after "?subject=" it does not work due to syntax error. Therefore, is there a way or another through html or php or any other scripting that will enable the user once clicking on the firewall_support@iuass.org link to open a new email message where the subject field is already filled out with the url in quest?

Any assistance in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
if ($cl['u']) $str[] = "<p>Because of access restrictions, your request to the above address is not allowed. </p><p>Please contact <a href=\"mailto:firewall_support@iuass.org?subject={$cl['u']}&body=Please unblock this URL, thanks\">IUASS firewall support</a> if you are of the opinion that this is not correct.</p>";
```

And its always useful to paste your code, for example on pastebin, so that we can have a look over it, especially in the case of syntax errors.

Moreover note that you will run into trouble if you do it the simple way I suggested, since urls will contain characters like &. You will have to replace all occurences of & by their htmlentities first.

Comment: Thank you very much ftiaronsem for your help which I'm actually in a dire need for. Well, I tried your solution but it is still giving me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /usr/local/www/sgerror.php on line 229. I have followed your advice and pasted the entire code on: http://pastebin.com/9esww6Wq which includes your suggested solution. I believe viewing that code will reveal to you where the mistake is. In addition, all urls are just domain names with no slashes or ampersands, may be hyphens and underscores only. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for pasting the code. A problem that meets my eye is in line 228. There is a final ' and a ; missing. But since the text of line 228 is included in line 229, I would strongly recommend to completely delete line 228. This will fix the syntax error. However it might be that another error pops up, and we might have to iterate two or three times to get the code bug free. Please always repost the most recent code on pastebin and I will try to check in more often during the day.

Comment: Thank you very much ftiaronsem for your time and your generous offer to check on my update. I'm actually reviewing and building the entire code line by line at the moment and will post my latest version as soon as I finish it. I am taking in consideration what Laurence and you have highlighted as both of your opinions are springing out of the same pot. Once again thank you...

Comment: At last I did it. Just posted the core part of the code that was problematic at: http://pastebin.com/1KfAzkk2. I inserted your code as it is, and it worked as exactly as expected, so I do thank you for you invaluable input in this matter. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
<?php echo "<a href='mailto:firewall_support@iuass.org?subject=" . $cl['u'] . "&body=Please unblock this URL, thanks'" ?>
```

This will create a hyperlink with the mailto URI you mentioned inserting the contents of $cl['u'].

Comment: Thank you very much Laurence for your prompt reply. I tried your solution and got this error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /usr/local/www/sgerror.php on line 198. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that line actually line 198?

What happens if you <php echo $cl['u'] ?> ?

Also, my answer above had a bug. Ending should be ?> and not just >

Comment: The original script can be reached at http://www.pfsense.org/packages/config/squidGuard/sgerror.php where my script in question is replacing script between lines 203-235. Thus line 198 is before my script where: $str[] = "<body>\n$body\n</body>"; - I also tried <?php echo $cl['u'] ?> and got the same error message on line 198. Much appreciated Laurence.

Comment: I have actually been trying to find out about that line's error, so I created the entire error page again and inserted your suggested code line, at this point the error was very clear at that code line as per this message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /usr/local/www/sgerror.php on line 229. Kindly suggest what I should do, thanks.

Comment: I hope someone will be able to assist here with the right code syntax, thanks.

Comment: TYpically the unexpected T_STRING happens when you don't close a quote properly. See here for examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685584/unexpected-t-string-error-in-php

Comment: One thing I noticed in your original code was that you enclose strings with single quotes ' ', and then parameters within them in double quotes " ", but not always -- for example right at the end the </body> and </html> are in doubles. It would be a good idea to keep it consistent, and thus easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you very much Laurence for your invaluable comments. I thought you dropped my question. I have been actually digging into my code (also trying to understand what I haven't changed), but still "standstill" with no progress :(

Comment: Have you tried cleaning up the " and ' like I mentioned? Make it consistent and the error may present itself...

Comment: Yes I have tried it very meticulously, but I still get the same error. On the other hand, I'm searching for similar cases in the hope that I may resolve it. Well, this is another way to learn, isn't it? Many thanks Laurence.

Comment: Can you update the code in paste bin then? I see that even in the code block you mentioned with $str being set to the body tag, that the quotes are inconsistent...some use ' some use " - look at how you assign the <HTML> tags, for example.

Comment: As a matter of fact there's nothing new that I can add to pastebin.com/9esww6Wq except to comment line 55 with a hash "#". All that I'm doing is just "trial and error" to pair quotes single or double in the function syntax; no success so far. I also looked into HTML tags, and with my little knowledge I don't see any typo or missing "/" or unpaired tags.. Still trying!!

Comment: I still see lots of inconsistent ones...for example here:

    function get_page($body) {
        $str = Array();
        $str[] = '<html>';
        $str[] = "<body>\n$body\n</body>";
        $str[] = '</html>';
        return implode("\n", $str);

See how differently they are handled (' for <html> and " for <body>)

Also, have you checked the _POST['u'] and _GET['u'] to see if they are not null?

Comment: Without your directions Laurence I wouldn't have noticed and learnt about such tricky syntax holes. So I do thank you for your time and effort spent on this issue. All the best.

Comment: For sure, this is the least I can do in return, thank you very much.